# React Typescript access keys of prop array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my Homepage which sends a modal component a profile like this.

```
<ProfileOverviewModal
     open={openProfile}
     onClose={closeAllModals}
     onCreateProfile={onCreateProfile}
     profile={state.profil}
/>
```

In my ProfileOverviewModal.tsx I have this props

```
type Props = {
  open: boolean
  onClose: () => void
  onCreateProfile: (values: ProfileModalFormValues) => void
  profile: Profil[]
}
```

When I console.log(profile) everything seems to work. This shows up in the console:

```
{Firstname: 'Eddy', Lastname: 'Browkin', __typename: 'Profil'}
```

But I can not access profile.Firstname && profile.Lastname for example

```
return (<h1>{profile.Firstname}</h1>)
```

Why is that? Any one can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be an array `profile: Profil[]` and excessing like single object?

Comment: I am fairly new. How do I access this type of types?

Comment: If your types are correct you're trying to read FirstName on an array (which is undefined). You'll need to map over `profile`, e.g. `return profile.map((prof) => <h1>{prof.firstName}</h1>)`

Answer (score 1):

Your profile prop expects array of object of type Profil, if you are passing single object then just change the prop as

```
type Props = {
  open: boolean
  onClose: () => void
  onCreateProfile: (values: ProfileModalFormValues) => void
  profile: Profil
}
```

And if you are passing array of profile then change you way you are accessing as below

```
return (<h1>{profile[index].Firstname}</h1>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have defined the type as `Profile[]` which is expecting array of Profiles. Just remove the `[]` from the type and you won't be seeing any error.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
return (
   <div>
      <h1> {profile.Firstname} </h1>
   </div>
)
```

Either use div tag or fragment i.e <> here h1 tag or everything else </>.
Also. in props ,  onCreateProfile does'nt seem to be correct. Please check that also.